# How to validate password from input field in HTML?

Tags: html, forms

I have the task of using a password field which checks if it has at least 8 characters, consists of at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lowercase character and 1 digit. How can I do this in the HTML input field using the pattern attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **pattern** for validation.

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
```

You can learn [more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

However, if you ever wanted to use some javascript, then HTML5 does enable some validation, even pattern matching, but I'm pretty sure you'd need some javascript to have this working and also compare the two values with confirm password field as well.

You can try this

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" pattern="^\S{8,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Must have at least 8 characters' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.password_two.pattern = this.value;" placeholder="Password" required>

<input id="password_two" name="password_two" type="password" pattern="^\S{8,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');" placeholder="Verify Password" required>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Sadly, I am not allowed to use JavaScript for this. The goal of this task is to only do it in HTML.

Comment: Just like I said, then alternatively you can use ** pattern matching **

Comment: I have edited my answer to use purely html, check the answer above